# User relationship to itself through another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I am getting confused on how to build the activerecord associations. I have an object that belongs to a user. This object was sent by several other users.

```
class Object < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :sender, :class_name => "User"
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :objects
end
```

I am confused on how to set up the "Sender" class, so that I can access @card.senders. I currently have it with card_id and user_id

```
class Sender < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :objects
end
```

Can't seem to get it to work. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to set up a HABTM *(has and belongs to many, or many-to-many)* relationship between `Object` and `User`. Try something like this.

```
class Object < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :senders, through: :object_relationships, source: :user, class_name: "User"
  has_many :object_relationships
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :owned_objects, inverse_of: :user

  has_many :objects, through: :object_relationships
  has_many :object_relationships
end

class ObjectRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :object
end
```

I prefer the `has_many ..., through: ...` method for HABTM associations over using `has_and_belongs_to_many` because I like the verbose-ness. You can read about choosing between the two [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has_many-through-and-has_and_belongs_to_many).

Comment: Ahh. Sounds good. Running into a snag when try to access @object.senders : "Could not find the source association(s) :sender or :senders in model ObjectRelationship. Try 'has_many :senders, :through => :object_relationships, :source => <name>'. Is it one of :object or :user?" Any ideas?

Comment: `source: :user` should do it.

Comment: Follow up question: I am trying to access all users that have sent an object to a user. In other words, given a user, all senders to that user. Any ideas?

Comment: You'll be better off creating a new question for this if you haven't already.